# clGetDeviceIds returns -1

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencl

I'm running Ubuntu Lucid with ATI Radeon Mobility 4800 HD. 3D support works (i.e. OpenGL applications run at normal speed), but when I'm trying to use OpenCL it fails:

```
#include <CL/opencl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#define CL_SAFE_CALL( call ) {                                                               \
    cl_int err = call; std::cerr << "EC: " << err << std::endl;                              \
    if(CL_SUCCESS != err){                                                                   \
      std::cerr << "Unsuccesful OpenCL call " << __FILE__ << " : " << __LINE__ << std::endl; \
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                    \
    } }

// OpenCL platform
cl_platform_id platform;

char* getPlatformInfo(cl_platform_id platform, cl_platform_info paramName){
  size_t infoSize = 0;
  CL_SAFE_CALL( clGetPlatformInfo(platform, paramName, 0, NULL, &infoSize) );
  char* info = (char*)malloc(infoSize);
  CL_SAFE_CALL( clGetPlatformInfo(platform, paramName, infoSize, info, NULL) );
  return info;
}

cl_platform_id createPlatform(){
  cl_platform_id platform;

  CL_SAFE_CALL( clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL));
  std::cout << getPlatformInfo(platform, CL_PLATFORM_VERSION) << std::endl;
  return platform;
}

// OpenCL devices of the platform
cl_device_id device_id;

void* getDeviceInfo(cl_device_id device_id, cl_device_info paramName){
  size_t infoSize = 0;
  CL_SAFE_CALL( clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, paramName, 0, NULL, &infoSize) );

  char* info = (char*)malloc(infoSize);
  CL_SAFE_CALL( clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, paramName, infoSize, info, NULL) );
  return info;
}

cl_device_id createDevice(cl_platform_id platform, cl_device_type type){
  cl_device_id device_id;

  // THIS IS LINE 44:

  CL_SAFE_CALL( clGetDeviceIDs(platform, type, 1, &device_id, NULL) );

  cl_uint* max_compute_units = (cl_uint*)getDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS);
  std::cout << "Max compute units: " << *max_compute_units << std::endl;

  return device_id;
}

int main(void){
  std::cerr << "createDevice:" << std::endl;
    platform = createPlatform();
  std::cerr << "createDevice:" << std::endl;
  device_id = createDevice(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU);
}
```

The following:

```
~$ g++ -o test test.cc -lOpenCL
~$ ./test
createDevice:
EC: 0
EC: 0
EC: 0
OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (923.1)
createDevice:
EC: -1
Unsuccesful OpenCL call test.cc : 44
```

I had libOpenCl from installations and I apt-get opencl-headers.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Radeon 4xxx OpenCL support is currently [in beta stage](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/pages/DriverCompatibility.aspx), so it might worth conteacting developers. Since the platform is found correctly, your OpenCL installation must be alright. BTW, if you by any chance are running your application over SSH/any other remote connection, you should set up X-authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error code of `-1` actually means `CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND` (look in the cl.h in your include\CL folder for reference). This might mean several things:

- *What is your GPU video driver?* Check if it does not support OpenCL at all.
- *Is your driver up-to-date?* Check if you have the latest version.

Comment: If all the above check out - see this nice guide (for Ubuntu) to making sure you installed all the right stuff to get everything working. http://www.thebigblob.com/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/

Comment: My GPU driver didn't support OpenCL though it was up to date. I had to download the experimental version.